# Show that $f$ is injective iff $(f(v_1),\ldots,f(v_n))$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over $F$.

$(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is a basis of $V$

$f: V \to W$ is a linear map

I have shown that $(f(v_1),\ldots,f(v_n))$ is linearly independent if $f$ is injective (from def. of linear independence and def. of $\operatorname{ker}(f)$)

I am stuck on how to prove the other direction ie suppose $(f(v_1),\ldots,f(v_n))$ is linearly independent, show $f$ is injective.

Comment: You're trying to show that $f$ is injective, so you want to show that if $f(v)=0$ then $v=0$. Since $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is a basis, you can write $v=a_1x_1+\cdots+ a_nv_n$. This should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $x \in V$ and suppose that $f(x)=0$. As $(v_1, \dots,v_n)$ spans $V$, it exists $\lambda_1, \dots \lambda_n$ such that
$$x=\lambda_1 v_1+ \dots +\lambda_n v_n$$

Which implies
$$0=f(x)=\lambda_1 f(v_1)+ \dots +\lambda_n f(v_n)$$

and as $(f(v_1), \dots,f(v_n))$ is supposed to be linearly independent, we get $\lambda_1=\dots=\lambda_n=0$ and finally $x=0$, proving that $\ker f$ is reduced to the zero vector and that $f$ is injective.